# Asp.net Core System.UnauthorizedAccessException when System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I got Access Exception in Asp.Net Core.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:****\source         \repos\webcore\webcore\wwwroot' is denied.'

This exception is generated by  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes

```
var webRoot = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

string hexString = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(reader.ReadToEnd());

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(webRoot, ConvertHexToBytes(hexString));
```

I was trying to run VS in Administrator mode and i added Network Services to User group but it didn't work out. Do you got any other ideas?

Comment: wwwroot is a folder, you need a file name

Comment: Why would you want your web server to write in the C: drive?

Comment: @Kzrystof i got only 1 drive right now

Answer (score 0):

My bad, Path is a directory. Embarrassing for me :\